# how to set read position to 1st string in std::istringstream?

Tags: c++, stdstring

in below c++ code, I am not able to rewind the read pointer to 1st string after doing some read operation on it by using getline():

```
 std::string token;
 std::string first;
 std:string str = "1,2,3,4,5";
 std::istringstream range(str);
 while(getline(range,token,','))
     cout<<"token="<<token<<endl;
 getling(range,first,',');
 cout<<first;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are consuming all the stream, and at the end of `while` the stream sets its `eof` bit. You need to `clear` the stream then seek back to the first position:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string token;
    std::string first;
    std::string str = "1,2,3,4,5";
    std::istringstream range(str);
    while (std::getline(range, token, ','))
        std::cout << "token=" << token << std::endl;

    // need these 2 lines
    range.clear(); // clear the `failbit` and `eofbit`
    range.seekg(0); // rewind

    std::getline(range, first, ',');
    std::cout << first;
}
```

Comment: Thanks vsoftco. this is exactly what I missed out in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the string and set the stream position to the begining:

```
range.clear();
range.seekg(0,ios_base::beg);
```